# Is there a way to check if dataframe is empty and if so to add a NA row?

Tags: r, rows

For example i have a dataframe that has nothing inside but i need it to run the full code cause it usually expects there to be data. I tried this but it did not work

```
ifelse(dim(df_empty)[1]==0,rbind(Shots1B_empty,NA))
```

Comment: Does it have columns but no rows?

Comment: Yes it has columns but no rows.

Comment: You are checking on a different object `df_empty` and rbinding another object `Shots1B_empty`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple question, OP, but actually pretty interesting.  All the elements of your code should work, but the issue is that when you run as is, it will return a list, not a data frame.  Let me show you with an example:

```
growing_df <- data.frame(
  A=rep(1, 3),
  B=1:3,
  c=LETTERS[4:6])

df_empty <- data.frame()
```

If we evaluate as you have written you get:

```
df <- ifelse(dim(df_empty)[1]==0, rbind(growing_df, NA))
```

with `df` resulting in a List:

```
> class(df)
[1] "list"
> df
[[1]]
[1]  1  1  1 NA
```

The code "worked", but the resulting class of `df` is wrong.  It's odd because this works:

```
> rbind(growing_df, NA)
   A  B    c
1  1  1    D
2  1  2    E
3  1  3    F
4 NA NA <NA>
```

The answer is to use `if` and `else`, rather than `ifelse()`, just as @akrun noted in their answer.  The *reason* is found if you dig into the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse) of `ifelse()`:

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
> with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
> element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

Since `dim(df_empty)[1]` and/or `nrow(df_empty)` are both vectors, the result will be saved as a list.  That's why `if {}` works, but not `ifelse()` here.  `rbind()` results in a data frame normally, but the class of the result stored into `df` when assigning with `ifelse()` is decided based on the test element, not the resulting element.  Compare that to `if{}` statements, which have a result element decided based on whatever expression is input into `{}`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
df_empty <- data.frame(x=integer(0), y = numeric(0), a = character(0))

if(nrow(df_empty) == 0){
  df_empty <- rbind(df_empty, data.frame(x=NA, y=NA, a=NA))
}
df_empty
#   x  y  a
#1 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 3):

We may need `if/else` instead of `ifelse` - `ifelse` requires all arguments to be of same length, which obviously will be not the case when we `rbind`

```
Shots1B_empty <- if(nrow(df_empty) == 0)  rbind(Shots1B_empty, NA)
```